# Cannot read PDF converted back from BLOB in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, base64

I am trying to save files in the DB using BLOB. I know it is not a very good practice but it needs to be done this way.

Anyway the problem that I am facing is that PDF files returned are not readable anymore. But all other files like docx, odt, txt, jpg and so on are working just fine when converted back from blob.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $file = $request->file('file');

    $data['data'] = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
    $data['extension'] = $file->guessExtension();
    $data['name'] = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $file = $this->fileRepo->create($data);

    return jsend()->success()
                  ->message("Resource Created Successfully")
                  ->data($file->toArray())
                  ->get();
}

public function download($id)
{
    $file = $this->fileRepo->find($id);

    $randomDir = md5(time() . $file->id . $file->user->id . str_random());

    mkdir(public_path() . '/files/' . $randomDir);

    $path = public_path() . '/files/' . $randomDir . '/' . html_entity_decode($file->name);

    file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($file->data));

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

    return response()->download($path);
}
```

Where am I going wrong and is there a special way to store the PDFs in a blob field?

Comment: Maybe the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8991231/717181) help?

Comment: As far as I can tell tell that guy solved it using a 3rd party lib to encode it in lines of length 72 but I am not sure how to do that in my application. How to encode a file in base64 in php using a certain length of lines?

Comment: How different files before upload and after download? something like `diff before.pdf after.pdf`.

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes there is a big difference in both the files. Git doesn't show much. It says `index 1e5308a..a6a4f0b 100644` which I am not sure what it means. But I looked at the files and the file that comes back is like 786.4 kB no matter if it was 2 MB or 3 MB originally. But phpmyadmin shows that all the 2/3 MB have been stored. So I am guessing that when the file comes back from the database somehow some of it is ripped?

Comment: @Rohan, are you sure it is a BLOB? AFAIK Mysql's BLOBs are limited to 64kB.

Comment: Medium blob. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I did a quick and dirty test here using MySql medium blob and few different pdf's with various sized files, (up to 6 meg) and they worked. Now that excludes the filerepo object and the form post and store, since your using it with other files the filerepo is likely ok, but what about the store? Can you verify the file gets uploaded correctly and is not being truncated or somthing? hope that helps.

Comment: If you write the file to disk after having saved it to the database in the `store` function, and then verify the file written is it fine then?
That is, add `file_put_contents(public_path().'/files/test.pdf', base64_decode($file->data));` before `return jsend()->success()`.

Comment: If that file works fine the next step is to take a look at what larval does to blob columns when getting them from the database.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the headers are being returned incorrectly and this is causing the file to appear unreadable.

Force them by replacing:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
return response()->download($path);
```

With:

```
$headers = array(
   'Content-Description: File Transfer',
   'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
   'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file->name . '"',
   );

return response()->download($path, $file->name, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your header return like that. you need to use Laravel's response ie.

```
public function download($id)
{
    $file = $this->fileRepo->find($id);

    $randomDir = md5(time() . $file->id . $file->user->id . str_random());

    mkdir(public_path() . '/files/' . $randomDir);

    $path = public_path() . '/files/' . $randomDir . '/' . html_entity_decode($file->name);

    file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($file->data));

    return response()->download($path)->header('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
}
```